# Simple Vim commands you wish you'd known earlier

Tags: vim

I'm learning new commands in Vim all the time, but I'm sure everyone learns something new once in a while. I just recently learned about this:

**zz, zt, zb** - position cursor at middle, top, or bottom of screen

What are some other useful or elegant commands you wish you'd learned ages ago?

Comment: technically, zz, zt, zb are positioning the *screen* with the cursor at the middle / top / bottom. to position the *cursor* at the middle / top / bottom use M, H, or L. Both sets of commands are useful!

Comment: Reading this post months or a year ago has since helped me every day.  dap is something I use to move paragraphs multiple times an hour, thanks to this post.

Comment: I have never picked up so many tricks from a page that has been marked as non constructive :) Thanks all.

Answer (score 332):

I really wish I'd known that you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> instead of <kbd>Esc</kbd> to switch out of insert mode. That's been a real productivity boost for me.

Comment: I remapped my Caps-Lock to an Esc. That's both easier than the normal Esc and Ctrl-C

Comment: @kmm: I remap my capslock to control, that's much easier than your solution. And works outside vim.

Comment: another popular was is to use 'jj' for ESC. I like this approach so far.

:map! jj <ESC>

Comment: You can also use CTRL-[ (which I like because it's both little fingers... just a little rotation of both hands).

Comment: use 'jk' as a variant on @claytron's. if you unknowingly are in INSERT mode already, jk leaves you where you were, so you can hit it whenever (credit: someone else...not my idea).

Comment: I have a keyboard where i don't use two keys: right-pinkie and the one on the right of that. [Portuguese Keyboard Layout](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/cf/KeyboardLayout-Portuguese.png)

Comment: I do "imap lkj <esc>" because sometimes I use 'jj' and 'jk' as variables or actual text--plus it has a really natural feel--just rolls off the fingers.. :)

Comment: This is a great tip, though be careful: it breaks VISUAL BLOCK functionality. You have to press ESC instead of Ctrl-C to properly insert a block new text, rather than just on a single line.

Comment: Keep in mind that using `Ctrl-c` to exit out of insert mode does not trigger the `InsertLeave` autocommand event. If you have any plugins or scripts depending on it, they won't work. See `:h i_CTRL-C`.

Comment: i prefer CTRL-[, it's standard vim hotkey that works everywhere

Comment: @Emile I like to map both `jk` and `kj` to <Esc> so that I can just hit both and it doesn't matter which one I happened to press first. It's almost like a single keystroke.

Comment: @gsk @Shrikant It looks like CTRL-[ works with both visual block and `InsertLeave`. Thanks to the comments on this answer, that's what I'm going to stick with (I'll have to un-learn ESC...).

Comment: Just gonna be "that guy" here and slightly contradict the claims that `jk` leaves you where you were in normal mode. This is not true when you are in the first xor last line of the buffer. (Though it *is* true if they are one and the same, as you wouldn't have anywhere to go but to stay put.)

Comment: UK keyboard layout user here. I remap 'Alt-Gr' to escape so it's under my right thumb. It makes vim much easier to drive.

Answer (score 205):

The most recent "wow" trick that I learnt is a method of doing complicated search-and-replace.  Quite often in the past, I've had a really complicated regexp to do substitutions on and it's not worked.  There is a better way:

```
:set incsearch             " I have this in .vimrc
/my complicated regexp     " Highlighted as you enter characters
:%s//replace with this/    " You don't have to type it again
```

The "trick" here (for want of a better word) is the way that you can use the search to create the regexp (and 'incsearch' highlights it as you enter characters) and then use an empty pattern in the substitution: the empty pattern defaults to the last search pattern.

Example:

```
/blue\(\d\+\)
:%s//red\1/
```

Equivalent to:

```
:%s/blue\(\d\+\)/red\1/
```

See:

```
:help 'incsearch'
:help :substitute
```

Comment: wow... I've been looking for something like this

Comment: yeah, I wish that I knew abou this sooner. But then again, that's what I say about everything I learn that is new in vim.

Comment: For anyone really loving this, try hitting `<Ctrl-R>/` to insert the last search query. (See `:help i_CTRL-R`) Really useful for similar to above, but you want to capture part of the search results. (like this: `%s:/\\([fF]rank\\) and mary/marie and \1/g`)

Comment: `:%s//...` also works with `*` (search word under cursor). A plugin called visual-star-search extends the functionality of `*` to match the whole text of a visual selection which makes it easy to search & replace the selected text, e.g. `v3e` (visually select 3 words) `*` (search) and `:%s//replacement/g` (replace all occurences with "replacement"). I use this so often that I have a mapping for the global substitution command: `:nmap <Leader>s :%s///g<left><left>`.

Comment: @idbrii since people reading may be Vim noobs (me), the `%s:` should be `:%s`, and for my system, I needed `\(\)` instead of `\\(\\)`

Answer (score 166):

I created this reference of my most used command for a friend of mine:

```
select                                   v
select row(s)                            SHIFT + v
select blocks (columns)                  CTRL  + v
indent selected text                     >
unindent selected text                   <
list buffers                             :ls
open buffer                              :bN (N = buffer number)
print                                    :hardcopy
open a file                              :e /path/to/file.txt
                                         :e C:\Path\To\File.txt
sort selected rows                       :sort
search for word under cursor             *
open file under cursor                   gf
  (absolute path or relative)
format selected code                     =
select contents of entire file           ggVG
convert selected text to uppercase       U
convert selected text to lowercase       u
invert case of selected text             ~
convert tabs to spaces                   :retab
start recording a macro                  qX (X = key to assign macro to)
stop recording a macro                   q
playback macro                           @X (X = key macro was assigned to)
replay previously played macro *         @@
auto-complete a word you are typing **   CTRL + n
bookmark current place in file           mX (X = key to assign bookmark to)
jump to bookmark                         `X (X = key bookmark was assigned to
                                             ` = back tick/tilde key)
show all bookmarks                       :marks
delete a bookmark                        :delm X (X = key bookmark to delete)
delete all bookmarks                     :delm!
split screen horizontally                :split
split screen vertically                  :vsplit
navigating split screens                 CTRL + w + j = move down a screen
                                         CTRL + w + k = move up a screen
                                         CTRL + w + h = move left a screen
                                         CTRL + w + l = move right a screen
close all other split screens            :only

*  - As with other commands in vi, you can playback a macro any number of times.
     The following command would playback the macro assigned to the key `w' 100
     times: 100@w

** - Vim uses words that exist in your current buffer and any other buffer you may have open for auto-complete suggestions.
```

Comment: You list "~X" to go to the mark with name X.  That doesn't work for me - instead I use "'X" (single quote).

Comment: Wow. Your absolutely right. When I was typing out the guide I guess my eye only seen the tilde and glossed over the back tick. I will update accordingly. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: I saw you are using u and U to convert text case. You can use ~ to toggle the case instead.

Comment: this list is nice, but I really want to know how did you draw this table? with VIM? which plugin? I'm looking for one currently.

Comment: I used VIM, but no plugin. However; using the select block feature made it relatively easy. 

Glad you found the list useful! ~brian

Comment: Ctrl-Q for block-selection is a specificity of mswin.vim that allows CTRL-V to paste. Most vim users would consider this evil and disable mswin.vim. "+P or Ctrl-R + is not that hard to type to insert clipboard contents.

Comment: thank you for shift-v, u and U!

@gaoshan88, ~ is toggling the case, but sometimes I need to set case explicitely for mixed case text, so u and U are very useful.

Comment: Omg, I've been using gu/gU for changing the case all these years, when I just needed the u/U in selection mode. I guess you can learn something new every day.

Answer (score 148):

**gi** switches to insertion mode, placing the cursor at the same location it was previously.

Comment: I was so happy when I found out about `g;` now this moves me to tears :-)

Comment: @longdeqidao not at all. It returns to the last insertion point. So you can scroll at your hearts content and it'll pull you back to where you were last inserting.

Comment: FYI, g; (which @PatrickOscity referred to above) puts the cursor at the place an edit was made. You can use it multiple times to go back in history. Noting this here because my vim help doesn't mention this for some odd reason.

Comment: Vim's intuitiveness never ceases to impress me. Since @PonyEars mentioned `g;` I tried if the "opposite" of it would be `g,` and lo and behold, we can go back and forward!

Comment: `a` is shorter. :) But `gi` is very intuitive indeed, with `g` usually being an opposite operation.

Comment: @ErwinRooijakkers a is completely different to gi though.

Answer (score 112):

```
:q!
```

I wish I knew that before I started vi for the first time.

Comment: as an emacs guy, that is the funniest comment i've read. not sure you meant it to be though. You made me happy today.

Comment: I remember trying vim and emacs for the first time on the same day, not knowing how to exit either. I thought to myself _what the heck is wrong with these people!?_

Comment: +1. The first time you start vim, the default message should be "write :q to quit". I would have save so much time lol

Comment: @JoséRamón But it _does_ show it on the screen by default if you enter vim without opening a file. Was this added recently? I can clearly remember trying vim years ago and it was there already. It also tells you to use `:q!` if you try to quit without saving the buffer.

Comment: @ivy_lynx yes, you may be right, but only if you open vim without files. Usually, the first time you open vim is because you need to edit a config file in Unix, so you write "$ vim file" and you can't find your way out. Or am I the only one?

Comment: @JoséRamón I think your experience is quite rare - considering nano is available and that most that are new to unix will probably not know about either one, I think it's a bit unlikely that the first time you run vim it will be with any files open. That said, it could have some hint for how to quit or get help but, I feel the design, as it is, is quite elegant and I'd do the same. From a design perspective, how many times will you expect someone who doesn't know vim, to deliberately use vim to edit a text file? And from the command line no less. If you panic, you can always close the terminal.

Comment: @Lernkurve Apparantly Apple very nearly launched the :qxxqa!!phone and didn't notice the i until it was too late.

Comment: troll.  may was well have said `:! rm -rf /`

Comment: @danielpops It's not a troll, it's a running joke that people who open vim for the first time (or accidentally) often won't know how to exit it again.

Comment: I sense a pattern that has roots from long ago - "Let's look at a typical novice's session with the mighty ed:" https://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/ed-msg.html

Comment: @danielpops How can you not see this is a joke?  Who is being trolled?

Comment: @DrEval why is it completely different?

Comment: @ErwinRooijakkers  Huh?

Comment: @DrEval I replied to the difference between `gi` and `a`. You said, somewhere, that they were "completely different".

Comment: @ErwinRooijakkers Well, they are. You're unlikely to ever be in a position where you can choose one over the other.

Comment: @DrEval, how are they different?

Comment: @ErwinRooijakkers One appends text after the current cursor location, and the other moves the cursor to the last point you edited text and puts you into insert mode.  Given that you didn't add your comment in the correct position, asking underneath an entirely different answer, one can see how this distinction might be lost on you!

Comment: Oooh indeed. :)

Comment: using ZQ instead.

Answer (score 57):

**^X-F** completes using filenames from the current directory. No more copying/pasting from the terminal or painful double checking.

**^X-P** completes using words in the current file

**:set scrollbind** forces one buffer to scroll alongside another. e.g. split your window into two vertical panes. Load one file in each (perhaps different versions of the same file). Do `:set scrollbind` in each. Now when you scroll in one, *both panes* will scroll together. Ideal for comparing files.

Comment: How to disable the scrollbind once I've enabled it?

Comment: *jinxed_coder*: `:set noscb` to turn it off and use `:set scb` to turn it on (not `:scrollbind`). `:h scrollbind`

Comment: Whoops. Corrected for ':set scrollbind'.

Comment: **^X-P** completes with preference to previous words in the file, **^X-N** with preference to the next words in the file.

Comment: You can also diff files by opening file1 and running `:diffsplit file2` or just starting vim with `vim -d file1 file2`. Vim automatically scrollbinds the two files.

Comment: just hit Ctrl-X in **insert** mode and you will be able to see all the available commands in the bottom i.e. `-- ^X mode (^]^D^E^F^I^K^L^N^O^Ps^U^V^Y)` for eg. **^X-D** for **Definition completion**

Comment: @PrabhatKumarSingh where is a good place to read up on these? E.g. for `^X ^D` I didn't find much with google (and I've yet to learn efficiently navigating `:h`)

Answer (score 57):

You can use a whole set of commands to change text inside brackets / parentheses / quotation marks/ tags. It's super useful to avoid having to find the start and finish of the group. Try `ci(, ci{, ci<, ci", ci', ct` depending on what kind of object you want to change. And the `ca(, ca{, ...` variants delete the brackets / quotation marks as well.

Easy to remember: change inside a bracketed statement / change a bracketed statement.

Comment: this isn't only for `c`.  You can do this with `d` to delete (e.g. di( or da(), `y` to yank, `v` to select etc.

Comment: Hello! I would like to know there the documentation for this is using `:help`? I can't find it anywhere. >_<

Comment: @MatejNanut: absolutely. Try `:help motion`. Then, look at `:help c` and `:help d` and `:help y` etc, which all take a motion.

Comment: @Peter I've checked those out before, but couldn't find mention of the peculiar "inner + delimiter" behaviour.  It turns out to be in `:help motion.txt`!  Thanks!

Comment: this tip is the sole reason why i switched to vi in the first place :)

Comment: If you're editing HTML or XML you can use `cit` to change the contents of the current tag. For example in `<span>Some text</span>`, if your cursor is over the "m" you can do `dit`to get `<span></span>`.

Comment: help: `:h motion.txt` and search/goto '6. Text object selection'

Answer (score 48):

Some of my latest additions to my Vim brainstore:

- `^wi`: Jump to the tag under the cursor by splitting the window.
- `cib/ciB`: Change the text inside the current set of parenthesis () or braces {}, respectively.
- `:set listchars=tab:>-,trail:_ list`: Show tabs/trailing spaces visually different from other spaces. It helps a lot with Python coding.

Comment: This needs more votes!  `cib` is great.

Comment: also:
ciw to change the current word (or caw, the same but left hand only)
ciW to change the current W=o.(r-d)
Sames with v instead of c will select in visual instead of replacing

Comment: cib is equivalent to typing "ci(". You can also do "ci[", "ci{", or (if your vimrc is set up correctly) "ci<", for other types of brackets.

Comment: Also, "cit" to change the text inside a tag. Very useful when working with XML/HTML.

Comment: it's also worth mentioning that you can suffix w/ the closing brace instead, should you prefer that. also, i've just learned about `ci}` & `cit` - wow, this is going to be _very_ useful. `vi[m]` is proving a very exciting program[s]!

Answer (score 48):

The asterisk key, <kbd>*</kbd>, will search for the word under the cursor.

<kbd>[</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> will take you to the definition of a C function that's under your cursor. (It doesn't always work, though.)

Comment: Try 'man ctags' if you're using *nix to learn how to generate a "tags" file that tells vim how to find the definition of any function or variable in many languages in addition to C.  Use ctrl+] to find the definition of the token under your cursor, or use :tag tokenToFind to find any token it knows about.  You can even start vim with "vim -t tokenToFind" to open the appropriate file and position the cursor at the function you need to edit.

Comment: the # key will search in reverse direction for the word under the cursor

Comment: https://github.com/bronson/vim-visual-star-search enables star search for visual selections. I don't want to miss it any more.

Comment: `[  + Tab ` will work always when you extend the `path` with required folders like `set path+=path/to/files`

Comment: How can I switch on search without navigation? `*` goes forward; `#` backwards; I want to highlight and stay at place.

Answer (score 47):

1. Don't press <kbd>Esc</kbd> ever. [See this answer to learn why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8020436/64290). As mentioned above, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> is a better alternative. I strongly suggest mapping your <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key to escape.
2. If you're editing a [Ctags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctags) compatible language, using a tags file and `:ta`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>, etc. is a great way to navigate the code, even across multiple files. Also, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> completion using the tags file is a great way to cut down on keystrokes.
3. If you're editing a line that is wrapped because it's wider than your buffer, you can move up/down using gk and gj.
4. Try to focus on effective use of the motion commands before you learn bad habits. Things like using 'dt' or 'd3w' instead of pressing x a bunch of times. Basically, any time that you find yourself pressing the same key repeatedly, there's probably a better/faster/more concise way of accomplishing the same thing.

Comment: Don't use Escape? That's heresy. Escape is your best friend, both on and off the job.

Comment: if it's such a good friend, why is it so far away on the keyboard?

Comment: because 99% of the people never uses it.

Comment: Escape is separated from other keys by a few inches on my keyboard.  You can't miss it.

Comment: #3 is awesome! Still learning new things ...

Comment: @BrianCarper Now look at your left hand after using it thousands of times each day for 20 years straight. Wait, which left hand?

Comment: map escape to caps lock using sharpkeys in windows or a different program.  gk and gj are news to me, and very helpful because I've been looking for something that would do that for a while

Comment: Don't understand #3 entirely; I use `:se nowrap` and then you dont have to worry about it.

Comment: Why, oh why #1? (The vi Wikipedia page does not mention this by now).

Comment: edited. see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8020436/64290

Comment: I mapped Caps Lock to CTRL because I use ctrl more than any other modifier in Vim and it entirely removes the need for crab-handing. `jk` is my ESC.

Answer (score 44):

`ZZ` (works like `:wq`)

And about the cursor position: I found that a cursor which always stays in the middle of screen is cool -

```
set scrolloff=9999
```

Comment: Didn't know that. `:x` does that as well

Comment: Not entirely accurate. Works like `:x`, which only saves the file if there are changes, whereas `:wq` always saves the file.

Comment: ZQ (works like :q!)

Answer (score 39):

**gv** starts visual mode and automatically selects what you previously had selected.

Answer (score 34):

**:shell** to launch a shell console from Vim. Useful when for example you want to test a script without quitting Vim. Simply hit **^d** when you done with the shell console, and then you come back to Vim and your edited file.

Comment: I guess `:!sh` was too hard. I prefer that because it's easier to compose command lines using registers/completions from the current buffer or e.g. use `%`/`%:h` for the current filename/dirname etc.

Comment: This one is very cool. I use it every day.. Before that it was, :wq, do cli stuff, reopen vim with same file.. Great optimization

Comment: Ctrl-Z to switch to shell and fg<ENTER> to go back to vim.

Comment: Put `map <Esc>! :shell<CR>` in your `.vimrc`, and you can launch the shell just with Alt+!, or Alt+Shift+1. (Mnemonic: `:!{cmd}` executes `{cmd}` with the shell.)

Comment: `:shell` will start a new nested shell level though. Whereas `ctrl-z` does not.

Comment: `:term` and `:vert term` are favorites 'cause they split open.

Answer (score 34):

This always cheers me up:

```
:help 42
```

Answer (score 31):

vimcryption

vim -x filename.txt

You will be asked for a passphrase, edit and save. Now whenever you open the file in vi again you will have to enter the password to view.

Comment: Sync this with your dropbox and you get a really nice password manager ;-)

Comment: But note that unless you `set cryptmethod=blowfish` (only available in 7.3+) it will use an algorithm with laughable strength. See `help encryption` for more detail.

Comment: Please do not use vim encryption, is not good encryption, and bad security is worst than none. More info: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/694

Comment: https://dgl.cx/2014/10/vim-blowfish meta-tldr: "fixed in Vim 7.4.399 [https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/vim_dev/D8FyRd0EwlE/bkBOo-hzTzoJ], for backwards compatibility reasons it needs to be a new cryptmethod, so use `:set cm=blowfish2`"

Answer (score 28):

### Build and debug your code from within Vim!

#### Configuration

Not much, really. You need a `Makefile` in the current directory.

#### To Compile

While you're in Vim, type **`:make`** to invoke a shell and build your program. Don't worry when the output scrolls by; just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> when it's finished to return to Vim.

#### The Magic

Back within Vim, you have the following commands at your disposal:

1. **`:cl`** lists the errors, warnings, and other messages.
2. **`:cc`** displays the current error/warning message at the bottom of the screen and *jumps to the offending line* in your code.
3. **`:cc n`** jumps to the `n`<sup>th</sup> message.
4. **`:cn`** advances to the next message.
5. **`:cp`** jumps to the previous message.

There are more; if you're interested, type **`:help :cc`** from within Vim.

Comment: works with more than just compiling code. Namely any task written in a makefile is a great use for this.

Answer (score 26):

Press `%` when the cursor is on a quote, parenthesis, bracket, or brace to find its match.

Comment: If the cursor is not over any of those it shifts to the right until it hits one of them.

Comment: I just tried it and it seems that it defaults left in you're inside. Experimenting a bit: If the cursor is at the dot, then: (<--.  )   or   . --(---->)   or  . --(--(----)--->)     or  nothing happens if you're to the right of all the braces (    )    .

Answer (score 25):

#### ^P and ^N

Complete previous (^P) or next (^N) text.

#### ^O and ^I

Go to previous (^O - "O" for old) location or to the next (^I - "I" just near to "O").

When you perform searches, edit files, etc., you can navigate through these "jumps" forward and back.

#### Marks

Press *ma* (m- mark, a - name of mark). Later to return to the position, type *`a*.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about ^O and ^I: that is awesome.  Might be worth including `:help jump-motions` etc in your answer in case anyone wants more information.

Comment: check out ShowMarks http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=152 . It will help you remember where and what all of your marks are in a buffer. you can toggle the visualization on and off with \mt

Comment: I don't get the difference between ^P and ^N...

Comment: @lajarre they cycle through the list of available completions in opposite direction

Comment: I often use ^O^O when opening up Vim after I noticed that I want to edit the last edited file again. Huge time saver!

Answer (score 23):

`^r^w` to paste the word under the cursor in command mode.

It is really useful when using grep or replace commands.

Comment: If it's the only word you want, then * in normal mode will search for the word under the cursor.

Answer (score 22):

Until [character] (`t`). It is useful for any command which accepts a range. My favorite is `ct;` or `ct)` which deletes everything up to the trailing semicolon / closing parentheses and then places you in insert mode.

Also, `G` and `gg` are useful (Go to bottom and top respectively).

Comment: best one here, though some of the others are useful too, I just knew about em all already

Comment: Also `f` instead of `t`, which will [action] up *through* that character; for instance, having the cursor on the beginning of a function argument, `df,` will delete it (in suitable languages, of course).

Comment: t and f are great for editing part of a camelCase variable. Eg, if you just duplicated a line and need to change firstVariable to secondVariable, position your cursor at the start of firstVariable, then ctV

Comment: T and F also work, but in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 18):

**^y** will copy the character above the cursor.

Comment: ... and ^E will insert the character below the cursor

Comment: doesn't work for me, it just moves a cursor to the beginning of text

Comment: @Alex This is to be used in Insert mode

Answer (score 18):

Typing a line number followed by `gg` will take you to that line.

Comment: : followed by line number does the same
:42 goes to line number 42

Comment: Typing a line number followed by G has the same effect.

Comment: `<number>go` goes to the `<number>`th character in the file.

Answer (score 17):

I wish I'd known basic visual block mode stuff earlier.  Even if you don't use Vim for anything else, it can be a big time saver to open up a file in Vim just for some block operations. I'm quite sure I wasted a ton of time doing this kind of thing manually.

Examples I've found particularly useful, when, say, refactoring lists of symbolic constant names consistently:

Enter Visual Block mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> for me on Windows instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>)

Move the cursor to highlight the desired block.

Then, `I whatever text` and press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to have the text inserted in front of the block on every line.

Use `A` instead of `I` to have the text inserted after the block on every line.

Also - simply toggling the case of a visual selection with `~` can be a big time saver.

And simply deleting columns, too, with `d` of course.

Answer (score 14):

q<letter> - records a macro.

and

@<same-letter> - plays it back.

These are by far the most useful commands in Vim since you can have the computer do a whole lot of work for you, and you don't even have to write a program or anything.

Comment: The use of `q` simplifies matters, but you aren't required to use it: just save into a named buffer the buffer command `"` - for example, using buffer `a` - `"ad$` ...

Comment: @Mei `q` records a macro; macros can contain commands, not just text, so `"ad$` is different from `qa`.

Comment: @Sortofabeginner That's irrelevant here. The command "ad$ puts text into buffer a and qa runs it.

Comment: @Mei `qa` doesn't run it; `qa` records it and `@a` runs it. It is true that you can write a macro in plain text, store it in register `a` with something like `"ad$`, and then execute it with `@a`, but this is quite a bit more work. There is a fundamental difference between cut-and-paste and record-and-run.

Answer (score 14):

#### Opening multiple files using tabs

```
:tabe filepath
```

#### Navigating between open files

```
gt and gT or :tabn and :tabp
```

#### Save the open session so that you can get back to your list of open files later

```
:mksession session_file_name.vim
```

#### Open a created session

```
vim -S session_file_name.vim
```

#### Close all files at once

```
:qa
```

#### Another command I learned recently

```
autocmd
```

It allows you to run a command on an event, so you could for example run the command make when you save a file using something like:

```
:autocmd BufWritePost *.cpp :make
```

Answer (score 12):

**qx** will start recording keystrokes. You can do pretty much any editing task and Vim remembers it. Hit **q** again when you're finished, and press **@x** to replay your keystrokes. This is great for repetitive edits which are too complex to write a mapping for. You can have many recordings by using a character other than **x**.

Comment: Also the same character 'x' is shared between the 'q' record macro command and the named clipboards ("x...). You can leave snippets of macros sitting around your file and copy them to a named clipboard (e.g. "xyy) and then play them back (@x).

Comment: And if you create the awesomist macro ever, you can past that clipboard into your _vimrc with a 'let @x = ""' (putting the macro in the "") and save it forever!

Answer (score 11):

I would have to say that one of my favorites is putting the help window in a new tab:

```
:tab help <help_topic>
```

This opens up help in a new tab and, as somebody that loves Vim tabs, this is ridiculously useful.

Comment: Buffers are the tabs of vim. They are better supported by the vim workflow. I suspect tabs were only added to vim because too many people did not understand buffers.

Comment: Ok so very soon after saying that, I found a use for tabs in vim. It is true that if you are using one buffer per tab, you need to learn about buffers. That is not how tabs were intended to be used in vim. Most advanced vim users use buffers the way tabs are used in most programs. Many people think tabs should have been named layouts in vim. They are mostly for having different collections of windows open in different tabs. You could also have a specific buffer that you go back to a lot open in one tab, and use the other tab for viewing all other buffers.

Answer (score 10):

```
:x #(Save and Quit a File)
```

Same as :wq or ZZ

Comment: For those who like `:wq` too much, I use `:command! Wq :wq<CR>` to deal with the pesky cases when I can't get off my shift key fast enough.

Answer (score 9):

`:b [any portion of a buffer name]` to switch buffers. So if you have two buffers, "somefile1.txt", and "someotherfile2.txt", you can switch to the second with simply `":b 2.t<enter>"`. It also supports tab completion, although it's not required.

Speaking of tab completion, the setting `:set wildmode=full wildmenu` is also very helpful. It enables complete tab completion for command-mode, as well as a very helpful ncurses-style menu of all the possible matches when using it.

Answer (score 9):

**cw**

Change word - deletes the word under the cursor and puts you in insert mode to type a new one.  Of course this works with other movement keys, so you can do things like **c$** to change to the end of the line.

**f + character**

Finds the next occurrence of the character on the current line.  So you can do **vft** to select all the text up to the next "t" on the current line.  It's another movement key, so it works with other commands too.

Answer (score 9):

#### Tabbed interface

Apart from split windows, you also can have tabbed windows. In the escape mode, type `tabnew`. You can open multiple tabs like this. To navigate between tabs, type `tabn`. This will move to the next tab. To move to a tabbed window, type `tabn2` to move the second tab and so on.

To close a tab, type `tabc`, `tabclose`, or just `close`.

If you are in a terminal emulator (basically terminal in GUI) then you can try doing `set mouse=a`. Once that's done, you can click inside the editor with your mouse. And this will also help you navigate between tabs by clicking, and also closing by clicking on the close button at the right side.

#### Align your code - Full file

Just type `G=gg` in the escape mode.

#### Fold your code

Say you have a function that is completed. You want to minimise (or fold) that part of code so that you can free up some space and reduce clutter. Just select the code. Then, type `fold`.

This will fold the code up. If you want to expand the code, just go there, and type `zo`. To fold again, type `zc`.

Answer (score 9):

**:%s,/search,/replace,**

You can use other characters than `/` (slash) to separate patterns for substitution. This way you don’t have to escape the slashes of file paths.

Comment: oh hell yes. I knew `sed` had this, but not `vim`. The more you know **♒☆**

Answer (score 8):

Taking [xcramps' suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276403/simple-vim-commands-you-wish-youd-known-earlier/1278752#1278752) one step further, I can't tell you how many times I've used:

> `:%!sort`

to sort a list of items in a file.

**Details:**

> `:`*range*`!`*command*

will execute a shell command on the specified range of lines. A range is usually specified as *start*`,`*end*

> Examples:
>   `1,3` specifies the first 3 lines 
>   `'a,'b` selects the text between bookmarks `a` and `b` 
>   `.,$` selects the entire document (`.` = first line; `$` = last line) 
>   `%` is a shortcut for `.,$` and also selects the entire document.

Feel free to mix and match numbers, bookmarks, `.`, and `$`.

Comment: I prefer vim's built-in :%sort. :help sort lists the many delicious options.

Answer (score 6):

I'm surprised no-one's mentioned Vim's windowing support. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd> is something I use nearly every time I open Vim.

Comment: I also use CTRL-W v :D

Answer (score 5):

```
ma
move cursor down
:'a,.!program
```

This will take all text between where you set the a mark (ma) to the current line (.), run it through program, and replace the contents of the marked region with the results. You can even use it to see the contents of a directory (for example) by making a blank line, then with cursor sitting on that line,

```
:.!ls
```

Oh, and you can set marks like this for a-z (i.e. ma), and

```
'a
```

will jump you to the position you marked as "a."

/ searches forward, and ? repeats search backwards without having to resupply search pattern.

Groovy stuff. vi is highly underrated. Once you get the hang of it, you won't ever want to use the IDE supplied editors.

Comment: For `:.!ls` I would more logically use `:r !ls` because it doesn't take input from my buffer and creates the line. I use `:r !uuidgen` e.g.

Answer (score 5):

I often make functions for editing tasks and store them in my `.vimrc` file, so I can find them again.

For example, reading .NET callstacks that have been converted into a single line:

```
function! FixCallStacks()
:%s;\[NLN\];\r;g
:%s;\[TAB\];\t;g
endfunction
```

Answer (score 5):

Comment out a range of lines:

1. First set a bookmark at the beginning of range:
   `ma`
2. Go the the last line in range
3. The command is:

   ```
   :'a,.s/^/# /
   ```

   Assuming `#` is your comment character.

Comment: Also, select the first column in each line in the range using CTRL+V or CTRL+Q, then insert the # at the beginning of each column using I (to insert before the selection) and then #

Comment: Or SHIFT+V, select a range, then

:'<,'>normal I#

Answer (score 5):

`:qall` and `:wqall` to close all the split screens.

Comment: Not sure if the short forms are assumed, but in case they're not: :qa and :wqa do the same thing.

Comment: There's difference.
`qa` - **Q**uit **a**ll
`wqa` - **W**rite & **Q**uit **a**ll

Answer (score 4):

```
:Te[xplore]
```

Tab & Explore (does a tabnew before generating the browser window)

Comment: I get `E464: Ambiguous use of user-defined command`

Answer (score 4):

I just discovered this one while browsing the Vim help:

```
:help index
```

This takes you to a single (*searchable!*) page with all the commands for all the modes.

So if you know that the command you're trying to remember/learn starts with or involves a certain keystroke, you can search for that and flip through all the possibilities. Or you can just browse the mode you're interested in to see/learn editing possibilities.

I can't count the number of times I've done just `:help` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> or whatever and gotten just the first thing, which is of course never the one you want. This is much better than `:helpgrep` IMO.

And into the .vimrc it goes:

```
nnoremap <silent> <F1> :help normal-index<CR>
inoremap <silent> <F1> <C-O>:help insert-index<CR>
```

`:help` still gets you to the default <kbd>F1</kbd> page.

Answer (score 3):

Use Vim bindings on the command line in Bash:

```
    set -o vi
```

In other, readline-using programs, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> to switch from Emacs to Vim bindings.

Answer (score 2):

In our software shop, variable declarations need to be sorted.  In the language that we use, multiple variables can appear on the same line.

```
new var1,var2,var3,etc
```

It is a real pain to go through and visually attempt to sort each and every variable.  The block highlighting, and sort command in Vim are my friends here:

1. Move the cursor to the first variable to be sorted.
2. Issue the v command to enter visual mode.
3. Move the cursor to the end of the last variable to be sorted in my case I enter $ to go to the end of the line).
4. Execute the !sort command to tell Vim to sort the highlighted text.

This will only work if their exists a 'sort' command on the underlying system.

Comment: What coding standard tells you to sort variable declarations alphabetically?

Comment: I program in a language called mumps. In a procedure, we can have 10's of variables all on one line. And there can be multiple lines. scanning through the list can be a real pain. Internally, we like to have to variable names sorted to make it easy to find.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not completely Vim. But I find the [cscope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cscope) integration really good, and it helps me a lot when hacking the Linux kernel.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd>, <kbd>g</kbd> to reach the definition of a function
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd>, <kbd>s</kbd> to find all the usages of a function, macro, or variable.

Answer (score 0):

**set confirm** allows you to quit Vim gracefully with **:q**. You don't need to use **ZZ** or other heavy-handed mechanisms which blindly save or discard all changes.

Answer (score -3):

For obsessive Vim configuration have a look at https://github.com/jmcantrell/dotfiles-vim

Comment: The link is unavailable.

Comment: The link is broken: *"404. This is not the web page you are looking for"*